# Adicionar novo inputText em página JSF ao pressionar uma tecla

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee, primefaces

Tenho um formulário aonde posso ter vários códigos cadastrados, gostaria de disponibilizar apenas um `inputText` de início, caso haja necessidade de inserir mais que um código eu aperto uma tecla atalho e então outro `inputText` aparece abaixo do primeiro e por ai vai.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Exemplo: Eu aperto `ctrl+1` e outro campo semelhante ao de cima aparece embaixo, toda vez que eu entrar com o atalho um campo novo aparece.

Como faço isso em `JSF`? Andei procurando por algumas coisas e vi que posso utilizar o `<p:hotkey>` para atalhos, porém ainda não sei como carrego um `inputText` apenas quando o atalho for pressionado.

Comment: Segue um link com uma solução no SOen http://stackoverflow.com/a/3409511/5165064